# Internal energy of an ideal gas as function of entrophy and volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

I'm trying to find internal energy of ideal gas as function of entrophy and volume. I think I can use this formula some way:

$$
\mathrm{d}U = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_V \mathrm{d}S + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_S \mathrm{d}V.
$$

I have no idea what to do next. The result should be:

[image]

I can see that there is isochoric heat capacity in two places. That's all I see. **I don't know how $V^{\kappa - 1}$ appeared there. Could you give me some hint where to start?**

Thank you for your time. I know this is just basic problem but my tries to search it failed. I will be glad for any advices.

Comment: Your expression for $U(S, V)$ has units of J K$^{-1}$ m$^{-3(\gamma -1)}$. Surely some mistake...

Comment: I would work backwards from their answer.  I would start out by taking the natural log of both sides, and then substituting the ideal gas relation for entropy S in terms of temperature and volume.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you provide assumes it is an ideal gas with constant $\gamma$.

One method (maybe not the best?) might be to find the entropy expression $S(T,V)$ and invert it to get $T(S,V)$. But for an ideal gas with constant $\gamma$, the relation between $U$ and $T$ is very simple.